# What components do I need to build Arduino based water pump controller?

Tags: motor

I have situation at my home which is causing us a lot of headache. We get drinking water only at midnight and someone has to wake up and switch on electric pump. This electric pump will pump water from water tank present at ground floor to the water tank present on the terrace.

I want to automate this electric pump operation and I have come up with following rules for it:

1. When water tank at ground floor is almost full then automatically turn on the pump which will push water from ground floor to the tank on the terrace.
2. When water tank on the terrace is full then switch off motor.

I am a professional software engineer and I have vast experience in Java, Scala, REST API, Big Data and all but I am totally new to Arduino so I do not know which Arduino components I need to build the above mentioned system.

Any guidance will be deeply appreciated.

Thanks,
Chandra

Comment: Float Switches are probably all you need.

Comment: In fact you can probably do it with discrete logic gates.

Comment: How far away are both tanks from each other? It might not be feasible to get a wire from both tanks to the Arduino. Is the pump near the tank on the terrace of near the tank on the ground-floor. If the pump is on the terrace, and you can't get a wire (for the float-sensor) to the ground-floor tank, you could add a RTC module to the Arduino, and always start the pump and 1AM. Have a float sensor in the tank to make the pump stop when the tank is full. Maybe add a flow sensor or something, to make sure the pump isn't pumping air (which might damage it (maybe))

Answer (score 3):

If you are controlling an AC pump, you might look into a PowerTail switch, which allows you to control AC power easily and relatively safely, but of course, if you are working with anything around water, be careful!  http://www.powerswitchtail.com/

Answer (score 1):

The easiest to build would be to use a real-time clock shield for time-keeping (examples: [make](https://duino4projects.com/an-arduino-real-time-clock-shield/) or [buy](https://www.bananarobotics.com/shop/Velleman-RTC-Shield-for-Arduino)) and a relay- or solid-state switch shield (popular item - many choices) for switching the pump. A simple wall power supply providing 5volts to run the Arduino completes it. Oh, yes - an Arduino board, too!